# How to verify recipient email address using utl_smtp in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have written a simple code to send emails from Oracle Plsql using utl_smtp. I want to verify the email address of the recipient, if it exists or not. How can I do that. I tried utl_smtp.vrfy but it doesn't seem to work. It always shows can not verify user. It seems this function doesn't work anymore in oracle.

Is there any other way by which we can verify the email of recipient . I am writing the below code and trying to verify email .

```
            declare
            l_mail_conn utl_smtp.connection;
            l_result utl_smtp.reply;
            l_sqlcode varchar2(1000);
            begin
            l_mail_conn :=utl_smtp.open_connection('smtp.antwerpen.be',25);
            utl_smtp.helo(l_mail_conn,'smtp.antwerpen.be');
            utl_smtp.mail(l_mail_conn,'abha@antwerpen.be');

            utl_smtp.rcpt(l_mail_conn,'abha.g123@antwerpen.be');

           l_result := utl_smtp.vrfy(l_mail_conn,'abha.g123@antwerpen.be');
            dbms_output.put_line(l_result.code ||' ' || l_result.text);

            utl_smtp.quit(l_mail_conn);

            exception when others then
            dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);

            end;
            /
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I doubt that it's feasible to verify if email exists or not. The only thing that yo can do is to check that email address corresponds to email's RFC format. There are a lot of them, just google. The full regex is quite big though. Also there is a procedure in Alexandria pl\sql library which provides validation https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils/blob/master/demos/validation_util_pkg_demo.sql

Comment: What exactly does it show? It may not be an Oracle issue - are you sure the server doesn't [have VRFY disabled](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/102648); or if it is allowed, that it just can't resolve that address? (I can't reach that server to see what it allows...)

Comment: An option to verify whether an email address is likely to be valid is to use Mailgun's SMTP validator - I have written an API for it here: https://github.com/jeffreykemp/mailgun-plsql-api

Comment: @AlexPoole   : VRFY command results in this message : "252 2.5.2 Cannot VRFY user; try RCPT to attempt delivery (or try finger) ". For all the email addresses whether they exists or not. Can you please let me know, how to be sure if the VRFY is enabled on the server.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp : I am afraid, I cannot use any simulator for this. I just need to write  code in en existing package that sends a mail to recipients. Is there any way to do that ? I want to make sure if the correctly formatted email address exists or not for a particular user...

Comment: Isn't that the server *telling* you that it is not enabled? Not surprisingly really. (See previous link.) Anyway, that's a message from the SMTP server, not an Oracle problem.